# How can I use IAM or Cognito Pool as an authentication method instead of API keys on Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I am using an AppSync API setup with AWS Amplify, I am getting the following error. Both IAM and Cognito Pool authorization methods are failing and produce this error. When I use an API key there is no problem.

```
    2019-05-15 23:15:44.215 15058-15058/com.example.aaa.amplify E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.aaa.amplify, PID: 15058
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aaa.amplify/com.example.aaa.amplify.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read awsconfiguration.json please check that it is correctly formed.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read awsconfiguration.json please check that it is correctly formed.
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration.readInputJson(AWSConfiguration.java:99)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration.<init>(AWSConfiguration.java:83)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration.<init>(AWSConfiguration.java:68)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration.<init>(AWSConfiguration.java:45)
    at com.example.aaa.amplify.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
 Caused by: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 1241 of {    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",    "Version": "1.0",    "IdentityManager": {        "Default": {}    },    "AppSync": {        "Default": {            "ApiUrl": "https://xxxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",            "Region": "us-west-2",            "AuthMode": "API_KEY",            "ApiKey": "da2-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",            "ClientDatabasePrefix": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-master_API_KEY"        },//        "Default": {//            "ApiUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",//            "Region": "us-west-2",//            "AuthMode": "AWS_IAM",//            "ClientDatabasePrefix": "xxxxxxxx-master_AWS_IAM"//        },    },    "CognitoUserPool": {        "Default": {            "PoolId": "us-west-xxxxxxx",            "AppClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",            "AppClientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",            "Region": "us-west-2"        }    },    "Auth": {        "Default": {            "OAuth": {                "AppClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",                "AppClientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"            }        }    }}
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:361)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:384)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration.readInputJson(AWSConfiguration.java:97)
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration.<init>(AWSConfiguration.java:83) 
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration.<init>(AWSConfiguration.java:68) 
    at com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration.<init>(AWSConfiguration.java:45) 
    at com.example.aaa.amplify.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I have tried directly connecting the API to the project and going through the auto setup with amplify add codegen xxxxxxxxxxxx. I am not having any luck

my awsconfiguration.json file:

```
//WORKS 
"AppSync": {
    "Default": {
        "ApiUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
        "Region": "us-west-2",
        "AuthMode": "API_KEY",
        "ApiKey": "da2-xxxxxxxx",
        "ClientDatabasePrefix": "xxxxxx-master_API_KEY"
    },

//DOES NOT WORK
   // "Default": {
   //     "ApiUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
   //     "Region": "us-west-2",
   //     "AuthMode": "AWS_IAM",
   //     "ClientDatabasePrefix": "xxxxx-master_AWS_IAM"
   // },
//DOES NOT WORK
    // "Default": {
    //     "ApiUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    //     "Region": "us-west-2",
    //     "AuthMode": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    //     "ClientDatabasePrefix": "xxxxxxxxxxx-master_AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
    // },
```

When I use the API key, I can connect to the back end, but when I try to use a user_pool or IAM role for authentication, I get the error. For development the API is fine, but now the correct setup is to use one of the other methods, Cognito pool or IAM

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the formatting error in the `awsconfiguration.json` file. For example if `API_KEY` is your default authorization mode configured on your AWS AppSync GraphQL API, you will have the following contents in the file.

```
{
  "AppSync": {
    "Default": {
      "ApiUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
      "Region": "us-west-2",
      "AuthMode": "API_KEY",
      "ApiKey": "da2-xxxxxxxx",
      "ClientDatabasePrefix": "xxxxxx-master_API_KEY"
    }
  }
}
```

If you have multiple authorization modes configured, you will have the following file:

```
{
  "AppSync": {
    "Default": {
      "ApiUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
      "Region": "us-west-2",
      "AuthMode": "API_KEY",
      "ApiKey": "da2-xxxxxxxx",
      "ClientDatabasePrefix": "xxxxxx-master_API_KEY"
    },
    "AWS_IAM": {
      "ApiUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
      "Region": "us-west-2",
      "AuthMode": "AWS_IAM",
      "ClientDatabasePrefix": "xxxxxx-master_AWS_IAM"
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can create multiple AWS AppSync clients to use the different authorization modes. When you need to use the `AWS_IAM` section from the file, you can do the following:

```java
AWSConfiguration awsConfiguration = new AWSConfiguration(getApplicationContext());
awsConfiguration.setConfiguration("AWS_IAM");
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. trackstarz408 is asking how to configure both the AWS backend and the client (Android in this case) for the AWS_IAM authentication mode. Ironically, the only usable information here is about the API_KEY mode, which the OP already said works but is undesirable since it can't be used in production. There are no errors for the OP to correct in this mode.